# Sorting category products not working

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, sort

I am using Avada theme and the sorting of the products on category page is not working. When i click on ascending and descending order the ordering of the products becomes random.

Please provide me solution script which i can put in functions file.
site url is autographpros.com

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order from the Appearance -> Customize section (woocommerce).

Ref: https://www.endocreative.com/customize-product-sorting-woocommerce/

Comment: Thanks for info. the setting i have already tried but no output. The website you can visit and see the issues happening.

Comment: Hi! Try: WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Product lookup tables > click Regenerate?